# Unity Collide two same GameObjects with same scripts. OnCollisionEnter() executes twice (once on each script)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two exactly the same GameObjects colliding.
Both have script atached, in which I have **OnCollisionEnter()**.

Context: two Armies of ships(*single game object with script: ShipBehaviour*) is fighting and one that have more ships inside lives, the other is destroys;

The problem is that **OnCollisionEnter()** being called twice (once on each GameObject),
therefore *final calculating number*(**ShipsInside**) is double than it should be.

**OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)** method:

```
if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Ship")
        {
            var shipBehaviour = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<ShipBehaviour>();
            if ( shipBehaviour != null )
            {
                
                    if(shipBehaviour.ShipsInside > ShipsInside)
                    {
                        shipBehaviour.ShipsInside -= ShipsInside;
                        Destroy(gameObject);
                    }
                    else if(shipBehaviour.ShipsInside < ShipsInside)
                    {
                        ShipsInside -= shipBehaviour.ShipsInside;
                        Destroy(shipBehaviour.gameObject);
                    }
                    else if (shipBehaviour.ShipsInside == ShipsInside)
                    {
                        Destroy(gameObject);
                        Destroy(shipBehaviour.gameObject);
                    }
                
            }
            return;
        }
```

So I want to execute **OnCollisionEnter()** logic in one GameObject and ignore it in other.

I have a solution: simly add in calculation division by 2. Than final number would be accurate. But obviosly it's not a right way to go about it.

Is there more afficient way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need a flag for this.

Your battle outcomes are exactly symmetrical, meaning either one party is the winner.

So the simplest fix in my eyes would be to only let the winning (or alternately loosing) party handle the outcome of the battle and do e.g.

```
// Note that your tag check is actually redundant
// this would already be enough and you don't need to remember assigning tags
if(collision.gameObject.TryGetComponent<ShipBehaviour>(out var shipBehaviour))
{             
    if(shipBehaviour.ShipsInside < ShipsInside)
    {
        ShipsInside -= shipBehaviour.ShipsInside;
        Destroy(shipBehaviour.gameObject);
    }
    else if (shipBehaviour.ShipsInside == ShipsInside)
    {
        Destroy(shipBehaviour.gameObject);
    }
}
```

This should be enough then since the other collision party already handles the other cases on their side anyway.

You could of course as well turn it the other way round and handle your own loosing case. The same way you might prefer rather only destroying yourself in the `==` case.

If you don't care about the one redundant subtraction (since the object is destroyed anyway) you could even as well shorten it down to

```
if(collision.gameObject.TryGetComponent<ShipBehaviour>(out var shipBehaviour))
{             
    if(shipBehaviour.ShipsInside <= ShipsInside)
    {
        ShipsInside -= shipBehaviour.ShipsInside;
        Destroy(shipBehaviour.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Nice and clean, works great! And nice note about replacing **tag check** with **TryGetComponent<>()**

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a flag to solve this.

```
private bool _collisionHandled = false;

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (_collisionHandled || collision.gameObject.tag != "Ship")
    {
        return;
    }

    var shipBehaviour = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<ShipBehaviour>();
    if (shipBehaviour != null)
    {
        if (shipBehaviour.ShipsInside > ShipsInside)
        {
            shipBehaviour._collisionHandled = true;
            shipBehaviour.ShipsInside -= ShipsInside;
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        else if (shipBehaviour.ShipsInside < ShipsInside)
        {
            _collisionHandled = true;
            ShipsInside -= shipBehaviour.ShipsInside;
            Destroy(shipBehaviour.gameObject);
        }
        else if (shipBehaviour.ShipsInside == ShipsInside)
        {
            _collisionHandled = true;
            shipBehaviour._collisionHandled = true;
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Destroy(shipBehaviour.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! The solution is working great! But it assumes that in the collision one side is always new(e.g. never collided before). Because after collision _collisionHandled always true, therefore logic not executes. And if both gameObject have _collisionHandled true - solution won't work.

Comment: You can set it back to false later. Maybe in OnCollisionExit or whenever is good for resetting it.

Comment: Well, I guess because both scripts run at the same time setting it back to false right at OnCollisionExit does not work (then second script executes as well). And after that there could be another collision straight away. So it's getting tricky to set it back to false

Comment: But if you only reset it back to false `OnCollisionExit` the other script wouldn't execute since it only happens in `OnCollisionEnter` ...